# mysql - updating a table setting a column with a complex condition

Tags: mysql

I have been working on this for a while now and this seems to be too complex. What I want to do is to update a column (`x`) with the operation: `(p * (100/c) ) / 100`.

`p` corresponds to a value of a date `x` and `c` corresponds to a value of date `x` minus one day.

I tried to create a stored procedure with loop but select statement doesnt work for me in the loop statement.

Here is my procedure which update nothing :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE firstqDate,date2 date;
DECLARE p, c float;
DECLARE cpt, val int;
SET @val = 0;
SET @cpt = (select count(*)-1 from quotes);
WHILE (val < 3)  DO
SET @firstqDate = (select qDate from quotes ORDER BY YEAR(qDate) ASC, MONTH(qDate) ASC, DAY(qDate) ASC limit 1,1);
SET date2 = (select qDate from quotes where qDate like DATE_ADD(@firstqDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY );
SET p = (select qOp from quotes where qDate like date2);
SET c = (select qCl from quotes where qDate like DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL val DAY));

update quotes
set qCh = (p * (100/c) ) / 100;
set val = val + 1;
end while;
END
```

EDIT : I did some updates to the stored procedure but still updating no lines!

```
BEGIN
DECLARE firstqDate,date2 date;
DECLARE p, c float;
DECLARE cpt, val int;
SET @val = 0;
SET @cpt = (select count(*)-1 from quotes);
SET firstqDate = (select qDate from quotes ORDER BY YEAR(qDate) ASC, MONTH(qDate) ASC, DAY(qDate) ASC limit 1,1);
WHILE (val < 3)  DO
SET date2 = (select qDate from quotes where qDate like DATE_ADD(@firstqDate, INTERVAL val DAY ));
SET p = (select qOp from quotes where qDate like date2);
SET c = (select qCl from quotes where qDate like DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL val+1 DAY));
set val = val + 1;
update quotes
set qCh = (p * (100/c) ) / 100
where qOp = p AND qCl = c;
end while;
END
```

I did some updates again to the stored procedures but no changes. i used some functions.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE p, c float;
DECLARE cpt, val int;
SET @val = 0;
SET @cpt = (select count(*)-1 from quotes);
WHILE (@val < 3)  DO
SET p = getp(@val, getd());
SET c = getc(@val+1, getd());
set @val = @val + 1;
update quotes
set qCh = (@p * (100/@c) ) / 100
where qOp = @p AND qCl = @c;
end while;
END
```

functions : 
get p:

```
BEGIN
declare d date;
select qDate into d from quotes ORDER BY YEAR(qDate) ASC, MONTH(qDate) ASC, DAY(qDate) ASC limit 1,1;
return d;
END
```

get c:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE c float;
DECLARE qDa date;
select qDate into qDa from quotes where qDate like DATE_SUB(qD, INTERVAL v DAY );
SELECT qCl INTO c FROM quotes WHERE qDate = qDa;
RETURN c;
END
```

getd:

```
BEGIN
declare d date;
select qDate into d from quotes ORDER BY YEAR(qDate) ASC, MONTH(qDate) ASC, DAY(qDate) ASC limit 1,1;
return d;
END
```

[image]

this stored procedure must calculate all qCh from p of qDate and c of the qDate minus one day. 
Thank you!

EDIT - Solved

Ouf! I finally managed to write this stored procedure :

```
BEGIN

DECLARE p, c float;
DECLARE cpt, val int;
SET @val = 0;
SET @cpt = (select count(*)-1 from quotes);
WHILE (@val <= 2)  DO
SET p := getp(@val, getd());
SET c := getc(@val+1, getd());
set @val := @val + 1;
update quotes q
set q.qCh = (getp(@val, getd()) * (100/getc(@val-1, getd())) ) / 100
where q.qOp = getp(@val, getd());
end while;
END
```

new getC

```
BEGIN
DECLARE c float;
DECLARE qDa date;
select qDate into qDa from quotes where qDate like DATE_ADD(qD, INTERVAL v DAY );
SELECT qCl INTO c FROM quotes WHERE qDate = qDa;
RETURN c;
END
```

I changed the code of function getC to add (-1) in the first iteration. now it is working!
Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: You have an `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE` - Wouldn't you want to limit that UPDATE to certain records in the quotes table?

Comment: I do not think i need a where statement after getting the values of the variables they will help to calculate qCh. no ?

Comment: *which update nothing* means what? What is the data type of `quotes.qCh` column?

Comment: qch is column whose values are calculated from p and c. p is a value of a certain date and c is a value of that date minus one day.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. i try to explain again the purpose of my query. i want to update all values of a column qCh by setting qCh to an operation (p * (100/c) ) / 100; but p and c are values of different conditions. i get p by a certain date ( lets say the 2nd oldest date in the table ) and c by that date minus one day. hope it is more clear.

Comment: I don't think you want to use LIKE as the comparison. Your current code assigns @firstqdate to the most recent qDate. Then you try to assign date2 to the following day as found in the quotes - which will be a null value. Once date2 is null, p is null.

Comment: Do you suggest i use the "=" operator instead of like ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your update cycle looks ok, even if i don't understand why you make 3 cycles. Shouldn't you use:

```
WHILE (@val < 3)  DO
```

Instead of

```
WHILE (val < 3)  DO
```

? Hope it helps

EDIT: 
You need to debug your cycle to know where the problem is.

Try this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @p, @c float;
DECLARE @cpt, @val int;
SET @val = 0;
SET @cpt = (select count(*)-1 from quotes);
SELECT 'Enter Cycle';
WHILE (@val < 3)  DO
SELECT 'In Cyle';
SET @p = getp(@val, getd());
SELECT @p;
SET c = getc(@val+1, getd());
set @val = @val + 1;
update quotes
set qCh = (@p * (100/@c) ) / 100
where qOp = @p AND qCl = @c;
end while;
END
```

Does you SP prints 'Enter Cycle' and 'In Cyle'? Does the value of p Variable prints? It is correct?